# How to remove characters in the middle of a string in bash

Tags: bash

In bash I have a string, and I'm trying to remove a character in the middle of the string. I know we can remove characters from the beginning or the end of a string like this:

```
myVar='YES'
myVar="${myVar#'Y'}"
myVar="${myVar%'S'}"
```

but how can I remove the one in the middle?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you know what character(s) to remove, you can use substitution in parameter expansion:

```
myVar=${myVar/E}  # Replace E with nothing
```

Or, if you know what characters to keep:

```
myVar=${myVar/[^YS]}  # Replace anything but Y or S
```

Or, if you know the position:

```
myVar=${myVar:0:1}${myVar:2:1}  # The first and third characters
```

Answer (score 7):

To remove just the **first** character, but not the rest, use a single slash as follow:

```
myVar='YES WE CAN'

echo "${myVar/E}" 
# YS WE CAN
```

To remove **all**, use double slashes:

```
echo "${myVar//E}"
# YS W CAN
```

You can replace not just a single character, but a long regex pattern. See more examples of variable expansion / substring replacement [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Answer (score 0):

A function I wrote, to trim from the middle of a string in bash:

```
folder=$1
declare -i maxLen=60

function trimMiddleString() {
  # param 1 = the initial string
  # param 2 = max length of trimmed string
  local loc_OrigStr="$1"
  declare loc_max=$2
  local loc_result=${loc_OrigStr}

  declare -i loc_lenStr=${#loc_OrigStr}
  if ((loc_lenStr > loc_max)); then
    declare -i numHalfMax=$((loc_max / 2))
    declare -i numShowBegin=$((numHalfMax - 3))
    local part1=${loc_OrigStr:0:${numShowBegin}}
    declare -i numSkip=$((loc_lenStr - numHalfMax))
    local part2=${loc_OrigStr:${numSkip}}
    loc_result="${part1}...${part2}"
  fi

  echo "${loc_result}"
}

displayFolder=$(trimMiddleString "${folder}" ${maxLen})
```